# Set width of \cmidrule or \cline

Tags: tables, xetex, tabularx, booktabs

I would like to prepare an income statement, so I found and modified a template for this on this site, giving the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
        
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{I}{@{}X<{\xdotfill}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\qq}r<{\qq}}

\makeatletter
        
\newcommand{\xdotfill}{\leavevmode\leaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill\hskip-\tabcolsep\kern\z@}
\makeatother
\newcommand\qq{\quad}
\newcommand\tablesec[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{#1}&&\\}
\newcommand\tabletitle[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c|}{\SEPx{2}#1}}
\newcommand\SEPx[1]{\vrule width 0pt height \dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A+2ex depth #1ex\relax}
\newcommand\SEP{\SEPx{0}}
\newcommand\?{\hphantom{0}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{IRR}
\tablesec{Revenue:}
\qq Revenue 1 & & $5,00$ \\
\qq Revenue 2 & & $1247,50$ \\
\qq Revenue 3 & & $24,00$ \\

\tablesec{Expenses:}
\qq Cost 1 & $392,00$ \\
\qq Cost 2 & $206,82$ \\
\qq Cost 3 & $21,51$ \\
\cmidrule{2-2}
\qq Total cost & & $620,33$ \\
\cmidrule{3-3}
Net income & & $656,17$ \\
\cmidrule{3-3}\morecmidrules\cmidrule{3-3}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The problem is here: the cmidrule under the totals is too wide, it fills the whole cell, I need it to be more narrow like this (see the red lines):
[image: The cmidrule is too wide]

Also, notice the red asterix: the booktabs-package which I'm using allows me to get a "double cline" in the last tabularx-rule, but this also causes a larger line spacing where it's used.

Maybe someone knows a solution :)

Thanks in advance,
Nino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to recommend that you load the `siunitx` package and employ its `S` column type to align the numbers in columns 2 and 3. Separately, use left- and right-trimming of the `\cmidrule`s in column 2, and left-trimming of the `\cmidrule`s in column 3. From an accounting class I took a long, long time ago, in a galaxy far away, I seem to remember that the rules should be as wide as the widest number in the respective columns. That's achieved by applying left- and right-trimming of the rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,},
            group-minimum-digits=4     % optional
           ]{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xdotfill}{\leavevmode\leaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill\hskip-\tabcolsep\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{I}{@{}X<{\xdotfill}}

\newcommand\qq{\quad}
\newcommand\tablesec[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{#1}&&\\}
\newcommand\tabletitle[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c|}{\SEPx{2}#1}}
\newcommand\SEPx[1]{\vrule width 0pt height \dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A+2ex depth #1ex\relax}
\newcommand\SEP{\SEPx{0}}
\newcommand\?{\hphantom{0}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{I *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]} @{}}
\tablesec{Revenue}
\qq Revenue 1 &    5,00 \\
\qq Revenue 2 & 1247,50 \\
\qq Revenue 3 &   24,00 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\qq Total income & & 1276.50 \\[1ex]
\tablesec{Expenses}
\qq Cost 1    & 392,00 \\
\qq Cost 2    & 206,82 \\
\qq Cost 3    &  21,51 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\qq Total cost   & & 620,33 \\
\cmidrule(l){3-3}
Net income       & & 656,17 \\
\cmidrule(l){3-3}\morecmidrules\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Am I correct that this solution realizes a fixed width of the second and third column? (table-format=4.2?) Or is there another purpose of this line?

Anyway: this works fine! Not really understanding the above yet, but it's way better than my temporary workaround/solution: using `\quad\underline{$[number]}`

Comment: @Nino - The option `table-format=4.2` instructs LaTeX to set aside enough space for 4 digits before the decimal marker and 2 digits after the decimal marker. The option `group-minimum-digits=4` instructs LaTeX to insert a "thousands separator" (default: `\thinspace`) between `1` and `247` in column 2 and between `1` and `276` in column 3, automatically. If you would rather *not* emply "thousands separators", remove the `group-minimum-digits=4` option and, instead, specify `group-digits=false`.

Comment: alright, replacing it by `group-digits=false` worked fine. But is it true that I cannot use formulas (`$`-symbols) anymore with your solution? Not a big deal, but I would keep the option open to replace the thousand separator by a point (.) instead of a space, is that possible?

Comment: @Nino - Why would you *need* to insert "formulas" in the two data columns? To set "." as the thousands-separator, be sure to set `group-digits=true` and `group-separator={.}`. Nothing more to it. :-) Incidentally, the user guide of the `siunitx` package is very well written and is easily accessible. If you need to learn more about this package, reading the user guide will be a far more efficient experience than posting queries on  the web.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right it's not needed, I just "learned" to do this, might have something to do with consistency. The siunitx-package provides some helpful features, I'm very thankful for helping.

Also, to complete the answer on my own question, I used the code `{\aboverulesep = 0mm \belowrulesep = 0mm}` in combination with the `\midrule` to remove the line spacing.